# Firebase Atomic Writes Across Multiple Locations error

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase version 9.8.0

```
 try{
        HashMap<String,Object>  m;
        m=new HashMap<>();
        FirebaseDatabase databasewritetoDB234;
        DatabaseReference myRefwritetoDB234;
        databasewritetoDB234 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRefwritetoDB234 = databasewritetoDB234.getReference("pagination").child("products_sub").child("mobile phone").child("apple mobiles");
        String key4= myRefwritetoDB234.push().getKey();
        m.put("products_sub/mobile phone/apple mobiles/"+key4,new Pagination("akey",(1+1)));
        FirebaseDatabase databasewritetoDB2345;
        DatabaseReference myRefwritetoDB2345;
        databasewritetoDB2345 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRefwritetoDB2345 = databasewritetoDB2345.getReference("ck");
        myRefwritetoDB2345.setValue(m).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()&&task.isComplete()){

                }else {

                }
            }
        });
    }

    catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("error",e.getMessage());
    }
```

E/error: Invalid key: products_sub/mobile phone/apple mobiles/-L6LFN1i_84LSn2vrw4l. Keys must not contain '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Comment: Can you share on which line you are getting this error?

Comment: Log.e("error",e.getMessage()); here

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `setValue` which doesn't accept paths in the keys; it only accepts property names, and values. The simplest fix is to use `updateChildren(...)`, which does accepts paths in keys:

```
myRefwritetoDB2345.updateChildren(m)...
```

Alternatively you can keep using `setValue(...)`, but in that case you'll need to create nested maps for the deeper-level values.